# Is there an easy way to view my Steam friends' screenshots?

Tags: steam

I really like the new screenshot functionality in Steam, but although it's meant to be a social thing you can share with people, Steam doesn't seem to make it easy to find which of your friends have uploaded anything.

I know you can set Steam to post a notification on the Blotter feed, but I barely ever look at that. And I'm certainly not going to trawl through all my friends' galleries every few days just to see the 'X has no screenshots available for your viewing' message a million times.

Is there a page that shows the screenshots my friends have uploaded, or anything like useful like that?

Comment: For all my googling, I can't find a way. This would make the screenshot feature a lot more fun.

Comment: more than that - it would make it useful/functional! not sure if Steam has a suggestion box anywhere, I imagine they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people asked on Steam forums to extend the API provided by Valve to allow access to screenshots but without them there is no easy way to implement what you ask for.

This is the [answer](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=20681482&postcount=3) of a Valve developer regarding this topic.

> We'd like to make lots more info
>   available via the Web APIs and publicly shared
>   screenshots would probably make sense.
>   However, we're always constrained on
>   time and resources as to which
>   features and work we can get done and
>   the public APIs haven't been a top
>   priority. Hopefully we'll be able to
>   catch them up with features and add
>   more functionality sometime soon.

Comment: hmm...disappointing. they really need a feature like that, I think.